# UITabBarController custom class in storyboard doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, segue

I've set up a `UITabBarController` in storyboard with 4 tabs, each linking to a `UITableViewController`. I've set the class of the `UITabBarController` to my own custom class `MyTabBarController` which is a subclass of `UITabBarController`.

Now I want to be able to access the 4 table view controllers that already exist on the storyboard from the `MyTabBarController` class so I can pass data from one to another. I have no idea how to access them from this point, all I know how to do is `@property (nonatomic, strong) MyTableViewController *tvc;` and then synthesising it, but that creates a new `MyTableViewController` object and doesn't link to the one already on the storyboard.

I hope that makes sense, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inherit this property from `UITabBarController`:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

You should be able to access its contents and identify which view controllers it knows about.

Comment: Thanks for that Philip. So i've inserted that property and synthesised it, now the first TableViewController doesn't load automatically anymore, it's just a black screen until I click on a tab. Also when I `NSLog(@"%i", [viewControllers count]);` I get 0 back - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of that.  As I said, you inherit the property that already exists when you subclass `UITabBarController`.  If you remove your property, then `NSLog(@"%i", [self.viewControllers count]);` should work.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for clarifying that, now I know to check the superclass for any properties I need. Thanks

Comment: One last thing, i'm a little confused how I access the properties of one of the viewControllers, I'm not quite sure of the correct syntax. What i'm currently doing is `[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setMyInt:1];` but when that specific viewController loads, the myInt value is 0. Can you help?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "viewController loads".  If it's in the `viewControllers` array, it must already have been loaded...maybe you've got the sequence of events reversed?  (The other thing is to use `NSLog(@"%@", self.viewControllers);` to make sure the array has the objects you think it has.)

Comment: I figured out what was wrong which goes with what you said. The `UITableViewController` is already loaded before I try to access it via the viewControllers array, and i'm testing the value of my property change in the `viewDidLoad` method in the  `UITableViewController`. Because the view loads before the property has been changed it's not working. How can I change the property before the view loads?

Comment: Where are you calling the `setMyInt` method now?  (I think it should work in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.)

Comment: I'm using the `setMyInt` method in the `UITabBarViewController` in method `didSelectViewController`. I'm just using myInt as an example, what i'm actually doing is loading JSON data from a PHP page into `TableViewController1` and i'm using the `UITabBarController` class to move some of the data into `TableViewController2`. Am I doing it right or shall I load the JSON data within the `UITableViewController` then just push it to any view controllers that uses the data?